# How to solve Kotlin's "unexpected error" in functions

Tags: function, android-studio, kotlin

Right now, I'm not working on any major projects. Just daily, bite-sized exercises and coding drills. This week = writing basic Kotlin functions. So out of my curiosity, why is Android Studio showing an "unexpected tokens" and "expecting ')' " errors for the params in my main function? The line that reads "(num1:5; num2:4)".

This is the exact format I'm seeing when I look up how to write it, but when I try to do, I keep getting errors. I even tried to copy and paste samples or snippets of code I found online, and the same thing always happens.

```
fun main()
{
    addition(num1:5; num2:4)
}

fun addition(num1: Int, num2: Int)
{
    println(num1 + num2)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is invalid.

Try with:

```
fun main() {
    addition(num1= 5, num2= 4) 
}

fun addition(num1: Int, num2: Int) {
    println(num1 + num2) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you to understand better!
[Kotlin Default Parameters](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#default-arguments)

Comment: Thank you for the resource! Much appreciated.